# how to access seperate data which is getting from requests in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I am  calling api and getting response back but dont know how to access it according to each key.

```
import requeste

def test(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    data={  'operator_id':request.POST.get('operator_id'),'mobile_number' :request.POST.get('mobile_number'),'amount':request.POST.get('amount')
            }
    r = requests.post(''https://www.somedomain.com/some/url/recharge'', data)
    print(r.text)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return HttpResponse('it worked')

else:
    return render(request, 'account/apitest.html')
```

response:

```
{ 
    "error":true, 
    "message":"",
    "NumberVerificationError":"",
    "Num‌​berVerificationResul‌​t":"",
    "NumberVerific‌​ationTransactionID":‌​"",
    "Rechargeerror":"‌​","Rechargeresult":"‌​",
    "Rechargetransacti‌​onID":"","Paymenterr‌​or":"",
    "Paymentresul‌​t":"",
    "Paymenttransa‌​ctionID":""
}
```

Comment: Your API expects post parameters as (key,value) or a json payload ?

Comment: should i do like this  r = requests.post('https://www.somedomain.com/some/url/recharge', json=data)

Comment: and if i modify like above it is giving me error while printing like this  print(r.text)

Comment: @KalyaniKulkarni What is the error ?

Comment: can you paste the (r.text or r.content )here ? if you dont find the content or text , go to python shell execute the lines of code after that put dir(r) it will display the methods are avail in r.

Comment: {"error":true,"message":"","NumberVerificationError":"","NumberVerificationResult":"","NumberVerificationTransactionID":"","Rechargeerror":"","Rechargeresult":"","RechargetransactionID":"","Paymenterror":"","Paymentresult":"","PaymenttransactionID":""}

Comment: above is the data which i get how to split it

Comment: You mean to get the message only from that dict ?

Comment: yes i want seperate data

Comment: it sends response in form of string so i am unable to access it as dictionary what i have to modify in above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert that into dict usin `python json`

```
import json
response = json.loads(r.text)
print response['message']
```

or You requests also have the option called `json()`

```
response = r.json()
print response['message']
```

Comment: thank you very much it works ..